# ¿Como puedo crear una nueva ventana sobre el gui que ya tengo de un canvas especifico?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo una grafica creada en un canvas mediante el metodo FigureCanvasTkAgg quisiera poder ampliarlo en una pestaña nueva dando click sobre la imagen, quisiera saber si es posible adjunto la parte del codigo donde creo el canvas

```
    def __grafica(self, x, y, z):

        f = plt.Figure(figsize=(5.3, 1.8), dpi=100)
        io = f.add_subplot(111)
        io.plot(x, y, 'ok', markersize=3)
        io.tricontourf(x, y, z, cmap='nipy_spectral', levels=14)
        io.tricontour(x, y, z, levels=14, linestyles='solid', cmap='nipy_spectral')
        ppo = io.tricontourf(x, y, z, cmap='nipy_spectral', levels=14)
        f.colorbar(ppo)
        self.__canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=self.__frame9)
        self.__canvas.draw()
        self.__canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=30, y=30)
```

Comment: A que te refieres con "ampliarlo en una pestaña nueva"???

Comment: mostrar la imagen que cree en el canvas en una ventana aparte

Comment: Hacer eso implica cambiar el parent del widget (es decir, donde fue creado). No es posible cambiar el parent de un widget una vez que fue creado.  Pero puedes simularlo volviendo a crear todo el grafico en una ventana nueva cada vez que el usuario haga clic y luego destruir u ocultar el grafico original.

Comment: En esta pregunta de SO en ingles se ahonda en el aspecto de cambiar el widget de parent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285648/can-you-change-a-widgets-parent-in-python-tkinter

Comment: vale ya pude modificarlo y hacerlo tal como me dijiste haciendolo en una ventana aparte pero quisiera saber algo un poco mas sencillo cada ves que llamo a la funcion grafica me esta creando un nuevo canvas como puedo dejar solo un canvas pero que solo se actualice lo que esta dentro de la grafica gracias

Comment: Esa es una pregunta diferente a la original. Podrías formular una nueva pregunta por favor?

Comment: Esto responde a tu nueva duda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124350/how-to-update-the-contents-of-a-figurecanvastkagg

Comment: si exactamente era lo que necesitaba muchas gracias